# How to connect to different websites using an API?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to make a website wherein if the user clicks on a button, he/she gets directed to UN's website for more info. Please help are bare with me because I am very much new to coding.

Comment: This questions title does not match it's content (an API would involve retrieving data with an HTTP request, but the body just talks about linking to another website). This question could also be answered with some very basic research about opening a new URL (a.k.a. performing navigation) with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of creating a button that links to a new page when clicked (note: this will error when run on StackOverflow because of restrictions on the iframe used for Snippets, but it will work in other environments):

```js
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  let btn = createButton("Open");
  btn.mousePressed(() => {
    // This opens a link in a new window or tab:
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example', '_blank');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It helped me a lot and my entire work has become way more simpler and presentable. Again thanks